# Marklogic search with ampersand

Tags: search, marklogic, ampersand

Suppose I am searching using one of the `cts:query` **API's**. I am looking for documents containing the phrase "*John and Jane*". Some of my documents have "*John & Jane*"(actually John &amp; Jane)  in them. I want them to be returned as well. Also consider reverse situation.

Does **Marklogic** provide any options to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Queries expressed as cts:query items or XML are easy to rewrite with XQuery `typeswitch` expressions. The discussion list thread at http://markmail.org/message/6hxmuqnpnfm73j4n has an example of something similar.

Comment: I think it would become a difficult job to rewrite the query for cases where my query string is(say in a cts:element-word-query)  "John & Jane and Joseph & Jordan and so on.." and my document contains "John and Jane and Joseph & Jordan & so on.." or a the same phrase with a different combination of '&' and 'and'. May be it's stupid on my part but I was hoping a mechanism somewhat similar to stemmed search would be in place to resolve this. I mean like 'running' resolves to 'run' and vice versa '&' would be resolved to 'and' and vice versa.

Comment: You're right that you could see a combinatorial explosion in cases like that. I would think they would be pretty rare, though. Your expansion code could check against a size limit and warn the user when the limit is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Mike gives a good suggestion, but it might be worth to take a step back and look at your problem first. From your comment on Mike's answer I take it that you look for something like thesaurus expansion, but for the 'and' and '&' instead of the other words.

I may be wrong, but to my knowledge MarkLogic doesn't provide features to take care of something like that automatically. Functions like `search:search` and `search:parse` are powerfull, but don't go that far. You are up to your own to take a search string like yours, break it into parts manually to wrap it in a cts:query, or use something like `search:parse` for that, and then pull tricks like that of Mike to walk through your query-tree, and expand any particular search query node you would like to expand in a particular way.

The markmail thread to which Mike points, gives an example of how to walk a query-tree, and manipulate it. A little heavy for this particular case, but there is a thesaurus module that can help in various general cases. The following chapter of the Search Dev Guide explains its features, and ends with a small example of how to apply it:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/thesaurus#chapter

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for that. I will have to see what I can build on that.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your term to search is `"John & Jane"`

In order to Search above word ,you can use following line

`let $inputSearchDetails ="John & Jane"`

`let $InputXML  := xdmp:unquote($inputSearchDetails, "", ("format-xml", "repair-full"))`